# how to give URI for file in android

Tags: android, android-storage

I want to access a pdf file from android phone from a particular location I have used

```
File videoFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsAppDocuments/ResumeAndroid.pdf");
String urri = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

but facing error file doesn't exist on location and tried.

```
Uri urii = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsAppDocuments/ResumeAndroid.pdf");
urii.toString()
```

in this case its giving error not absolute path.
kindly help

Comment: Which android version you are using for testing?

Comment: Andoirdx i m using

Comment: There is nothing in your code that could give the error you mentioned.